# Simple string comparison shows wrong results

Tags: php

It sounds very simple and it should be but I've got some issue and can't find it.

I have a file with words on each line, like

```
dog
dog
dog
dogfirend
dogandcat
dogcollar
dog-food
```

The above should display me: `3` (since there are only 3 full matches of `dog`)

I'm trying to read the file and check how many times the word `dog` is inside. The problem is that it doesn't count at all and shows `0`. This is what I have

```
$word = "dog";
$count = 0;

$handle = fopen("dogs.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if ($word == $line) {
             $count++;
        }      
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Could there be a file line-terminator issue? Can you `var_dump($line);` each time and see what you get?

Comment: Most likely all of your `$line`s have a newline at the end. Use [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on them

Comment: I added `trim` like `if ($word == trim($line, "\n"))` but now shows `0` for count

Comment: I just checked, using `if ($word == trim($line))` and I get `3` as a result. Make sure there are no spaces or something in your file, or `trim($word)` as well. ("_doesn't count at all and shows 0._" btw, your code doesn't output anything)

Comment: That's very strange. When I add this second parameter of `trim` in my case `"\n"` shows 0 counts. But when I changed it as you `trim($line)` it shows the correct answer of `3`.

Comment: Now seems that it is working perfectly and the issue was the newline. Thanks!

Comment: You could try `"\r\n"`

Comment: Thanks, everything works fine now. You can post it as an answer and I will accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines in your file are separated by a newline. This newline is included in your `$line` variable.

From the [fgets()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) manual: "*Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, or a newline (which is included in the return value), or an EOF (whichever comes first).*"

You need to [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) your `$line` first, so those characters get removed:

```php
$word = "dog";
$count = 0;
$handle = fopen("dogs.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if ($word == trim($line)) {
             $count++;
        }      
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
echo $count
```